# How to use match on String value with Scala?

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, design-patterns, match

I'm trying to iterate on a String value to change each occurence of it. 
For example i want that "1" become "one", "2" become "two", etc.

I've done this :

```
  override def toString = {  
    val mapXX = init.map(_.clone);  
    var returnVALUE = mapXX.map(_.mkString).mkString("\n")

    for(c <- returnVALUE){
        c match {
          case 1 => "one";
          case 2 => "two";
          ...
          case _ => "";
        }
    }
    returnVALUE
  }  
}
```

It didn't change anything of my list, i have the same display of my list. Nothing has changed.

Did someone knows how can we iterate on each character of a String value in order to replace each character by something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're doing. Try

```
returnVALUE.map {
  case '1' => "one"
  case '2' => "two"
  case '3' => "three"
  // ...
  case _   => " "
}.mkString
```

and this should be the last line of `toString`.

`String#map` accepts a function from `Char` to something (e.g. to `String`).

If `returnVALUE` is `"1 2 3"` then this produces `"one two three"`.

When the last line is `returnVALUE` this means you return the original value of `returnVALUE`, not the modified value.

Comment: Thank you, that's it, i didn't know that we can use mkString at the end of a match, I also changed case _ => "\n" to display each line , thanks again

Answer (score 3):

A `for` comprehension without the `yield` clause doesn't create any results. It can only be used for side effects, which good Scala programmers try to avoid.

Maybe something like this.

```
val numberNames = Map(0 -> "zero", 1 -> "one", 2 -> "two").withDefaultValue("too big")

val result = List(2,0,1,4).map(numberNames)
//result: List[String] = List(two, zero, one, too big)
```